# Why will addEventListener not focus on input elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that when a user hovers over an input element, it automatically focuses and they can type in it. It doesn't give me any errors in the console, but neither does it work.

Here is my code:

```js
var field1 = document.getElementById("code")
const field1hover = function() {
  field1.focus()
}
field1.addEventListener("mouseenter", field1hover)

var field2 = document.getElementById("encoded")
const field2hover = function() {
  field2.focus()
}
field2.addEventListener("mouseenter", field2hover)
```

```html
<input id="code">
<input id="encoded">
```

--------------update---------

It just started working, I don't know why.

Comment: that's strange works for me [see example here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPH84968SEAD)

Comment: Your code works as expected. What is your question?

Comment: *all I'm doing is improving the ux of my website* That is definitely **not** an improvement by any means. It yields all sorts of unexpected behaviours and as such, by definition is bad UX.

Comment: I'm guessing that the question is how to get focus (if that's even possible) if user is focused on element outside of web page like url bar etc.

Answer (score 2):

So this creates a different UI experience that's certainly not "normal" but I'll ignore that and pretend you have a good use case here. I would simply do it like this, a small refactor so you can clean your code up a bit:

```js
    const inputHovered = function() {
        this.focus()
    }
    
    var field1 = document.getElementById("code")
    field1.addEventListener("mouseenter", inputHovered)
    
    var field2 = document.getElementById("encoded")
    field2.addEventListener("mouseenter", inputHovered)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="code" />
<input type="text" id="encoded" />
```

We can take it a step further if you want this to happen for all of your inputs by just querying for all of your inputs and looping through them to add this listener to all of them. Don't forget to clean up your event listeners to prevent a memory leak.

Also don't forget to make sure you're keeping this accessible for users who do not use a mouse.